# How To Translate Numbers Using PO File?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, translation, po

I'm trying to translate a WordPress theme to tibetan. Now, the issue is that Tibetan numbers are different than English numbers.

I can't put them straightaway as following:

`msgid "1"`

`msgstr"-tibetan number-"`

This causes replacement for "1" but not for "11" or "111". So how do I replace numbers? Is their a wildcard in PO that I can use?

Or any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible with a PO file because you will need to translate each numbers. Maybe you can try to developp your own translation system and use an existing script that translate characters and numbers in tibetian. [See this](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/tibwrite/) for example.